# How can I skip spaces when parsing a haskell string

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, spaces

I have the following definition in a parser using the Haskell `ReadP` library:

```
expr = chainl1 comp (string "===" >> return fun6)
```

How can I skip spaces before the `===` operator? I don't know how to include it in this syntax.

Comment: I think the question is too broad, since it sounds like an answer would need to explain basic syntax, monads, and monadic parsing. There are lots of tutorials that deal with parser combinator libraries you can check out

Comment: I know how to parse, i am just having some trouble with syntax in this one. Everything is working but when i try to parse strings with spaces before operators, they fail....

Comment: have you tried `spaces >> string "===" >> return fun6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReadP` has [`skipSpaces`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#v:skipSpaces) for exactly that usecase; your parser then becomes

```
expr = chainl1 comp (skipSpaces >> string "===" >> return fun6)
```